# Did Ilsa Faust lie?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

In the opera *Turandot* which is held in Vienna, Ilsa Faust failed to kill the Austrian Chancellor with a gunshot.

While Ethan saved the chancellor by shooting his arm, when Ilsa was asked why she wanted to kill the Chancellor, she said that she also doesn't want to kill him but only hurt and save him.

But in the scene where Ethan shoots his shoulder and the Chancellor bends down to the right, Ilsa shoots and the gunshot mark on the chair is where the Chancellor's heart would be if he were there.

Then how come she only wanted to hurt him? Did she lie?